# DolphinDB: How to insert an array vector using MultithreadedTableWriter (MTW) in C++？

Tags: c++, arrays, dolphindb

I want to insert an array vector (e.g., best 5 quotes) using MTW in C++, which data form is available for insertion? It would be better if there is an example script.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data as a vector in the `std` namespace, as shown below:

```
vector<int> p{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};        
if(!writer.insert(errorInfo, 2, "BB", "f3007450-7e0a-bde0-ca8c-8c73379207a0", p)){            
  std::cout << "insert Failed for " << errorInfo.errorInfo << std::endl;        
}
```